# Pattern matching with case classes with type parameter doesnt work

Tags: scala

I have some case classes with an `unapply` in the corresponding companion object, which I use for pattern matching as follows:

```
trait DAO [T] {
  def create: Int
  def insert(model: List[T]): Int
  def update(id: String, name: String): Int
  def delete(id: String): Int
  def all: List[T]
  def find(id: String): List[T]
  def findSome(id: String): List[T]
}

sealed trait Service[A]
final case class Create[A](implicit val dao: DAO[A]) extends Service[Int]
final case class Insert[A](model: List[A], implicit val dao: DAO[A]) extends Service[Int]

object Create_{
  def unapply[A](in: Create [A])= Some(in.dao)
}
object Insert_ {
  def unapply[A](in: Insert[A]) = Some((in.model,in.dao))
}

case class F(id:String)

implicit val abc = new DAO[F] {
  def create = 1
  def insert(model: List[F]) = 1
  def update(id: String, name: String) = 1
  def delete(id: String) = c1
  def all = List(F("Test"))
  def find(id: String) = List(F("Test"))
  def findSome(id: String) = List(F("Test"))
   }

def b[A](in: Service[A]) = {
  in match {
    case Create_(dao) => dao.create
    case Insert_(model, dao) => dao.insert(model)
  }
}
```

The REPL complains with the following error when I load the above file:

```
scala> :load ..../tools/scala/macros/test.scala
Loading ...../tools/scala/macros/test.scala...
defined trait DAO
defined trait Service
defined class Create
defined class Insert
defined class F
defined object Create_
defined object Insert_
abc: DAO[F] = $anon$1@3e776a48
<console>:65: error: type mismatch;
found   : List[Any]
required: List[A] where type +A
case  Insert_(model, dao) => dao.insert(model)
```

It doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
Insert[+A,B](model: List[A], implicit val dao:DAO[B])
```

You are allowing different types for the list elements for the model and the DAO, but the DAO requires a single type:

```
  def insert(model:List[T]):Int
```

You could fix this by requiring the types of insert to be the same.  You are then guaranteed to be passed the right type of model for your DAO.

```
Insert[A](model: List[A], implicit val dao:DAO[A])
```

Comment: i have tried many  option including the one you are suggesting.
In fact that was my first option but it does not compile too

Comment: Let me know if the second answer doesn't sort everything, and I'll take another look

Comment: the last line in the pattern match

`case Insert_(model,dao) =>dao.insert(model)`
is causing the compile error:
` <console>:94: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Any]
 required: List[A] where type +A
                case  Insert_(model, dao) => dao.insert(model)
                                                                                ^
`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. In the pattern matching i use of course Create_ and   Insert_ 
    ` def b[A](in:Service[A]) ={
         in match { 
          case Create_(dao) => dao.create case Insert_(model, dao) => dao.insert(model) 
      }
     }`

Answer (score 1):

The remaining issue is that `case class Create[A](implicit val dao: DAO[A])` is the same as `case class Create[A]()(implicit val dao: DAO[A])`. So `case Create(dao)` is illegal, it would be `case Create()` instead. Either use `case Create_(dao)` or remove `implicit val` from the `Create` class definition.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. In the pattern matching i use of course Create_ and Insert_

     ` def b[A](in:Service[A]) ={
           in match {
             case Create_(dao) => dao.create
             case  Insert_(model, dao) => dao.insert(model)
          }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

the solution was

```
 def b[A](in: Service[A]) = {
  in match {
    case Create_(dao) => dao.create
    case Insert_(model:List[A], dao:DAO[A]) => dao.insert(model)
 }
```

There are still warning!!!

```
 scala> :load .../tools/scala/macros/Test.scala
 Loading .../tools/scala/macros/Test.scala...
 defined trait DAO
import scalaz.{Free, $tilde$greater, Id, Coyoneda}
defined trait Service
defined trait Command
defined type alias Functor
defined class Create
defined class Insert
defined class Execute
defined class F
defined object Create_
defined object Insert_
defined object Execute_
lift: [A](service: Service[A])scalaz.Free[Functor,A]
abc: DAO[F] = $anon$1@2a071108
<console>:219: warning: abstract type pattern A is unchecked since it is   eliminated by erasure
            case  Insert_(model:List[A], dao:DAO[A]) => dao.insert(model)
                                ^
 <console>:219: warning: abstract type A in type pattern DAO[A] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
            case  Insert_(model:List[A], dao:DAO[A]) => dao.insert(model)
                                       ^
<console>:217: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: Insert(_, _)
          in match {
             ^
 b: [A](in: Service[A])Int
```